# Localização do main em um projeto com padrão MVC

Tags: java, mvc, arquitetura-de-software, projeto-de-software

Dentro de um projeto pautado no padrão MVC onde o `main()` da aplicação deveria estar localizado? Pensando um pouco imaginei que fosse no modelo, pois ele contém as partes mais "complexas" de código, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: O `main()` é o `main()`, não é nem **M**, nem **V**, nem **C**. O `main()` não tem que ter partes "complexas" não, ele só deve inciar a aplicação.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você está se baseando em uma premissa falsa, que toda a parte do sistema tem que ser ou M (model), ou C (controller) ou V (view).

O caso do `main()` é o mais emblemático, ele não é nenhum deles e está localizado fora do MVC. No modelo MVC, o M corresponde as classes que modelam o seu domínio, enquanto que o V e o C ditam como o usuário (ou algum outro sistema externo) pode manipular o seu domínio.

O MVC diz qual é a forma que você organiza o seu modelo e como ele interage com o mundo externo (ou como o mundo externo interage com ele). Em especial, ele dita que não se deve poluir o seu domínio com lógica de visualização ou com lógica de controle de fluxo. E se possível, não poluir a visualização com lógica de controle de fluxo e nem o seu controle de fluxo com lógica de visualização. Isso daí não diz nada e não tem relação nenhuma com coisas que não pertencem ao seu domínio e nem interagem diretamente com o ele, tal como o `main()` por exemplo (ou uma biblioteca para a escrita de documentos XML que o seu projeto use, se você quiser um exemplo diferente).

Além disso, complexidade de código não tem relação com o fato de ser ou não ser parte do modelo ou não. O MVC se propõe a reduzir a complexidade total ao dividir claramente as três camadas, mas ele nada diz sobre a complexidade de cada camada isoladamente. Aliás, o controller tende a ser a camada mais complexa por ele estar acoplado tanto ao model quanto ao view.

Por fim, o `main()` tem tipicamente o propósito de subir tudo que for necessário, o que possivelmente significa criar/instanciar o controller e muitas vezes também o modelo e a view. Embora o `main()` possa criar o controller, ele não faz parte dele, pois ele não gerencia o fluxo de dados da aplicação. O `main()` também não está no modelo, pois ele não é uma peça fundamental do seu domínio (e se você colocasse o `main()` no modelo, estaria subvertendo o MVC, uma vez que ele também cria o controller). Obviamente ele também não é view.